# Strip everything but text from html

Tags: c#, html, string

Our CMS allows users to enter text using a html editor, so when reading text into the webpage I can text like this:

```
&#xD;&#xA;      <p>&#xD;&#xA;      <strong>text text. more 
text</strong>&#xD;&#xA;      <a href="http://blabla>blabla</a> even more text...
```

How can I strip everything but text including , and . and similar characters ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming this is html (not xhtml), I would use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) to parse it, and access [InnerText](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack):

```
static void Main()
{
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(@"&#xD;&#xA;      <p>&#xD;&#xA;      <strong>text text. more text</strong>&#xD;&#xA;      <a href=""http://blabla>blabla</a> even more text...");
    string s = doc.DocumentNode.InnerText;
    // s is: &#xD;&#xA;      &#xD;&#xA;      text text. more text&#xD;&#xA;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load it into `XDocument`/`XElement` object and get the `Value` property, it will actually returns you the inner text of the element. You'll have to do that for every element by using depth enumeration of the xml/html tree (and add spaces between every inner text node).

- `<P>hello</P>` will get you "hello"
- `<P>hello</P><P>hello</P>` will get you "hellohello" using rootNode.innerText - that's why you'll have to use it for every node to get "hello hello".

Answer (score 0):

use

var a = new Regex("<[^>]+/?>");
var v = a.Replace("my dirty text here", "");

v will now contain the text without attributes and tags.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Regular expressions to filter HTML from a web page to retrieve only the text itself, like this:

```
Regex.Replace(requestHtml, "<.*?>", string.Empty)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use XML :

`rootNode.innerText`

But your input has to be checked before as a normalized XML.