# strip HTML and CSS in C#

Tags: c#, html, string

I'm creating mails in one of my solutions and need to provide both html and plaintext mails from a given html page.

However, I haven't found any real good way to strip html, js and css from whatever html template the customers might provide.

Are there any simple solution to this, perhaps a component that handle all this or do I need to start puzzle with regexp? And is it even possible to create a bulletproof regexp for all possible tags?

Regards

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393982/strip-everything-but-text-from-html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) a go. It has methods for extracting the text out of an HTML Document.

You basically just need to do the following:

```
  var doc = new HtmlDocument();
  doc.LoadHtml(htmlStr);
  var node = doc.DocumentNode;
  var textContent = node.InnerText;
```

Answer (score 1):

As a component that can strip html: [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You might find the [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) helpful to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here: [HTMLAgilityPack parse in the InnerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346144/htmlagilitypack-parse-in-the-innerhtml). There is an answer how to do it using [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

In this page you can find a really fast algorithm to strip HTML from a string input. Although there are some issues with invalid HTML, it's still a great resource.
http://www.dotnetperls.com/remove-html-tags